# How many wires and connectors can I put in the new slim pancake 3.5"x3.5" LED controller boxes

Tags: electrical, wiring, led

I live in Ontario Canada. I have included a picture of the box.  It appears that the inside of the wiring compartment is about 6.56"(3.5x1.5x1.25)
I would like to be able to and have added 3 x 14/2 wires (Picture included).

I want to make sure that is ok.  Otherwise, I do not know how you are able to run power in and then send runners out in two different directions to other lights (Picture included).

- **Update**
  This sure has got mixed responses.  I contacted the manufacture and this is their response.[DawnRay](https://dawnray.space/)
  Keep in mind these driver boxes and size are the norm for current pancake stye LED lights.
  I included the drawing below, to the manufacturer, of my intention to string the lights together.
  I have asked for further clarification and posible documentation that would answer why these boxes are ok, contrary to the info in guides like this [Box Fill Calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/construction/box-fill#how-to-calculate-box-fill)
  **Response from DawnRay** - "*Yes you can run 2 of the 14/2 wire through the box, one in and one out. And continue to do so.*"

[image]

- Also would it be acceptable to install say a 4x4 junction box opposite the manufactures box and run most of the wiring into that box and then run a wire from the junction box into the brown manufactures control box?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I worked with the Ontario Electrical inspector(ESA) and this is the answer that was accepted to pass my inspection.

- For the 6.56"(3.5x1.5x1.25) driver boxes that come with my DawnRay lights, I can have 2 14/2 cables.  For example one from the switch and one to run to the next LED light or what ever you have down stream.

So he allowed exactly what is in the drawing I submitted.  He would not allow any other wires in those boxes, BUT, he would allow a 4x4 junction box attached before the driver box that could be pulled through the light opening.

Thanks for the input from others.

Comment: To be clear, your additional box is connected to the driver box with cable, and the entire assembly, both boxes, and enough unstapled cable to allow this, can all be pulled through the ceiling opening *and he's grandfathering in* that your additional box can also contain additional cables not related to the specific fixture?    I mean that's both amazing (for you) and a little surprising.

Comment: And also, I think it's obvious, but you wouldn't do *both*, right?  If you have a second box behind the driver box, all your splicing will be there, you won't have a second 14/2 in the driver box. Right?

Comment: Jay613, yes I am thrilled!  Both boxes needed to be able to be pulled through the hole. I was only requied to do this for a couple of the lights.  98% were just simple 1 in and 1 out(2x 14/2).  The inspector was great to workl with and very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The wiring compartment in your controller box is only large enough to accept a single 14/2 or 12/2 cable. That means your fixtures must be wired with a "star" topology, i.e. each fixture fed with a single cable from a presumably central switch or junction box.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but In Ontario this is for sure not the case.  As the manufacture sugjested, the Electrical inspector(ESA) accepted 2x 14/2(1 in and 1 out) but no more.

Answer (score 1):

6.56" is basically enough for a single 14/2 with ground. See [this box calculator](https://www.omnicalculator.com/construction/box-fill#how-to-calculate-box-fill) for some of the details. That isn't even, technically, enough for 12/2 with ground. However, assuming this is actually ETL (which I think it is, hard to see in the picture upside down) or UL listed then it has passed some reasonable testing and design evaluation and I would be surprised if it couldn't handle one 12/2 cable properly. But that *does* mean you should not put multiple cables into the box.

The instructions should make it more clear, but one cable, *and never more than one*, does have some logic to it for a device like this. Use an ordinary box (e.g., a 4" square metal box) to join "in", "out" and "to this light fixture". Then run a short NM cable from that box to the light fixture mini-box.

Note that I bounced between 14/2 and 12/2. That was deliberate. For code reasons, any wire/cable installed outside of the light fixture itself *must* be 12 AWG (or larger) for a 20A circuit and 14 AWG (or 12 AWG or larger) for a 15A circuit. Historically most circuits have been 15A with 20A only for "big stuff", but more and more circuits are 20A because of the requirements for kitchen, bathroom, etc. So a 20A circuit being used partly for lighting (even though lighting itself now uses very little power compared to incandescent lighting) is not unusual and in those cases you must use 12 AWG throughout, *including spurs to individual fixtures*.

Comment: thanks for the details suggestion.  JFYI, In Ontario the Electrical inspector(ESA) accepted allowing 2x 14/2(1 in and 1 out) for these small LED driver boxes and passed my inspection. Your mileage may vary depending on your location and regulations.

Answer (score 0):

Not an electrician, but I would say you are ok with the 3 14/2 cables you show you have. Anymore would be overload.

You could put in a junction box, but it would have to be accessible from the attic.  Not sure it would pass code just stuffed in a hole next to one of the lights.

Comment: Well, it's not clear if this counts as a junction box for fill purposes, but if it is, it should be 14 cu in, possibly 16 if you count the splice for the driver.  Can't really tell how much space the box has from here.

Comment: In Ontario the Electrical inspector(ESA) accepted 2x 14/2(1 in and 1 out)   but as you stated, he would NOT accetpt 3x 14/2 in these small boxes